# How to query all key-value pairs for a pattern from Redis without making multiple requests

Tags: rust, redis, pipeline

I'm trying to get all the key value pairs for a given prefix from Redis, without making many network requests using Rust. The answers so far suggest using bash or making multiple requests.

Answer (score 1):

The best method I've found is to use a lua script to construct the response. The example below is not the fastest since we can use `EVALSHA` to reduce our request size.

Code:

```rust
let raw_kv: Vec<Option<(String, Vec<u8>)>> = tokio::time::timeout(
    timeout,
    redis::cmd("EVAL")
        .arg(
            // use KEYS instead of SCAN since EVAL is already blocking
            "
    local keys = redis.call('KEYS', ARGV[1]);
    if next(keys) == nil then return keys end;
    local out = {};
    for i=1,#keys do out[i] = {keys[i], redis.call('GET', keys[i])} end
    return out;
    ",
        )
        .arg(0) // no manually passed in keys
        .arg(pattern) // custom pattern to search for
        .query_async(&mut self.conn),
)
.await;
```

Docs: https://docs.rs/redis/latest/redis/struct.Cmd.html#method.arg

Comment: KEYS is a slow command, you'd better DO NOT use it in production, especially when you have a large data set.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that Redis doesn't do this. You *can* get all the keys for a pattern using the [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys/) or [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan/) commands. Then you can [GET](https://redis.io/commands/get/) the keys that are returned. And you can write a [Lua script](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/eval-intro/) or use JavaScript to [write a function](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/) to do this for you.

However, this is neither very convenient nor is it particularly fast, especially if you have a lot of data. And, the KEYS command is problematic as it block the main Redis thread while it runs. Furthermore, if you are running a cluster, this gets more complex as the keys you want to find are going to be on multiple servers.